# Numpy, inserting one matrix in another matrix efficiently?

Tags: python, numpy, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication, array-broadcasting

I am trying to make an outer product of two vectors more efficient by removing zero elements, doing the outer product and then enlarging the resulting matrix with rows of zeros or inserting into a zero matrix. (Sparsifying the matrix using scipy does not really work since the cost for conversion is high and I am doing it over and over again.)

```
import numpy
dim = 100
vec = np.random.rand(1, dim)
mask = np.flatnonzero(vec > 0.8)
vec_sp = vec[:, mask]
mat_sp = vec_sp.T * vec_sp # This is faster than dot product
# Enlarge matrix or insert into zero matrix
```

Since it is the outer product of two vectors I know the zero rows and columns in the original matrix, they are are indices in the mask variable. To see this,

```
a = np.array(((1,0,2,0))).reshape(1,-1)
a.T * a
>> array([[1, 0, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 4, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

I have tried two different solutions: one using numpy's `insert` method and append method to the `mat_sp`variable. The whole thing becomes a for-loop and really slow.

```
for val in mask:
    if val < mat_sp.shape[0]:
        mat_sp = np.insert(mat_sp, val, values=0, axis=1)
        mat_sp = np.insert(mat_sp, val, values=0, axis=0)
    else:
        mat_sp = np.append(mat_sp, values=np.zeros((mat_sp.shape[0], 1)), axis=1)
        mat_sp = np.append(mat_sp, values=np.zeros((1, mat_sp.shape[1])), axis=0)
```

The other approach is creating a zero matrix of size `dim x dim` and then creating a giant index vector from the mask, through two for loops. And then using the index vector to insert the matrix multiplication into the zero matrix. However, this is also super slow.

Any ideas or insights that could solve the problem efficiently would be great as the sparse matrix product takes 2/3 of the time of the non-sparse.

---

Using the example of @hjpaul we get the following comparison code

```
import numpy as np
dims = 400

def test_non_sparse():
    vec = np.random.rand(1, dims)
    a = vec.T * vec

def test_sparse():  
    vec = np.random.rand(1, dims)
    idx = np.flatnonzero(vec>0.75)
    oprod = vec[:,idx].T * vec[:,idx]
    vec_oprod = np.zeros((dims, dims))
    vec_oprod[idx[:,None], idx] = oprod


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    print('Non sparse:',timeit.timeit("test_non_sparse()", setup="from __main__ import test_non_sparse", number=10000))
    print('Sparse:',timeit.timeit("test_sparse()", setup="from __main__ import test_sparse", number=10000))
```

The code gives an improvement of course depending on the dimensions of the vectors and the number of zeros. Above 300 dimensions and around 70% zeros gives a modest speed improvement that is increasing with the number of zero elements and dimensions. If the matrices and mask are the same over and over again it is surely possible to get a greater speedup.

(My fault in doing logical indexing was doing `idx` instead of `idx[:,None]`)

Comment: what are the dimensions you're dealing with?  Also if the zeros are not in blocks not sure you'll gain any efficiency with this transformation.

Comment: Both `np.insert` and `np.append` create new arrays.  They don't work in-place with points like list operations.   Using them repeatedly in a loop is a bad idea.  And read their code to see just how much work they do.

Comment: "I am trying to make a vector dot product more efficient by removing zero elements, doing the dot product and then enlarging the resulting matrix with rows of zeros or inserting into a zero matrix." - it seems like you'd spend more time fiddling with the zeros than you save in the dot product. Also, a vector dot product produces a scalar.

Comment: Are you talking about an *outer product*?

Comment: @karakfa For any dimension but say around 100-1000. I have timed the code and it gives a speed improvement (given that I can get it back to its original form).

Comment: @user2357112 sorry meant the outer product. I thought it would not work, because of the overhead of copying and indexing but if my timeit measurements are correct then removing the zeros doing the outer product is much faster (given that I can put it back in its original form.)

Comment: Experimenting with your `test_sparse` shows that it's [definitely not doing what you think it's doing](https://ideone.com/VFwqo7).

Comment: @user2357112 had a typo ```where...[1]``` should be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way to insert one matrix into another is with indices.

To illustrate with your outer product:

```
In [94]: a = np.array(((1,0,2,0)))
In [95]: idx = np.where(a>0)[0]
In [96]: idx
Out[96]: array([0, 2])
In [97]: a1 = a[idx]
```

The outer product of the condense array:

```
In [98]: a2 = a1[:,None]*a1
In [99]: a2
Out[99]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 4]])
```

Set up the result array, and use block indexing to identify where the `a2` values go:

```
In [100]: res = np.zeros((4,4),int)
In [101]: res[idx[:,None], idx] = a2
In [102]: res
Out[102]: 
array([[1, 0, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 4, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Direct outer of the uncondensed array:

```
In [103]: a[:,None]*a
Out[103]: 
array([[1, 0, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 4, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
In [104]: np.outer(a,a)
Out[104]: 
array([[1, 0, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 4, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

If `a` was 2d, (n,1), this outer could be written as `np.dot(a.T,a)`.  `dot` involves a sum, in this case of the size 1 dimension.

I think `a` would have to quite sparse to benefit from this extra indexing work.  With scipy sparse matrices I find that a sparsity on the order of 1% to have any speed advantage, even when the matrices are premade.

---

```
In [105]: from scipy import sparse
In [106]: A = sparse.csr_matrix(a)
In [107]: A
Out[107]: 
<1x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [108]: A.A
Out[108]: array([[1, 0, 2, 0]], dtype=int64)
In [109]: A.T*A           # sparse matrix product, dot
Out[109]: 
<4x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
In [110]: _.A
Out[110]: 
array([[1, 0, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 4, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Did you forget that `((1,0,2,0))` is just `(1,0,2,0)`? You made a 1D array where it looks like you wanted a 2D array.